# Appgyver Supersonic $http returns with status 200 but gives data as 404 not found

Tags: angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app, appgyver, supersonic

I'm new to Hybrid application dev, using Appgyver Supersonic

I'm trying to make a http request for user to login, below is the code:

```
$http.post({
url: 'http://www.somesite.com/check.login.php',
data: $scope.logd,
crossDomain: true,
cache: false,
headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
// do something
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
// do something
});
```

In response I get data as:

```
<html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0'></head><body><h1>404 Not Found</h1>/app/login/[object Object] was not found.</body></html>
```

response status is 200,

I'm also new to angularjs,
Can you please let me know what could be the issue here and the possible actions that can be taken?

Comment: Are you getting anything in the javascript console? How are you debugging?

Comment: Hi @area28 , tried to user the browser's  console. It fills up with angularjs errors! Like - Error: [$interpolate:interr]. can't see any post's happening..

Comment: It worked, instead of $http.post({..}), I used the method: "POST" parameter.. Thanks.